# Upload image from phonegap app to WCF service

Tags: wcf, cordova, file-transfer

I am trying to upload image from my mobile to WCF server using phonegap file transfer API.
Following is my code. But I am not able to upload the image to server. Please give some suggestion.

Test.html

```
<body >
  <div data-role="view" id="uploadView"  data-reload="true">

    <div data-role="content">


       <button onclick="getphoto();">get a Photo</button>

       <img src="" id="myimg" style="border:1px solid #0f0;height:200px;width:200px;" />
    </div>


 </div>
<script>

function getphoto() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(
        uploadPhoto,
        function(message) {
            alert('get picture failed');
        },
        {
            quality: 10,
            destinationType:navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType:navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
        }
    ); 
}


function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
    document.getElementById("myimg").src = imageURI;

    var options = new FileUploadOptions(); 

    options.chunkedMode = false;

    options.fileKey = "recFile"; 

    var imagefilename = imageURI; 

    options.fileName = imagefilename;
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg"; 

    var ft = new FileTransfer(); 

    alert(imagefilename);

    ft.upload(imageURI, "http://myserver/MyAppService.svc/SaveImage", win, fail, options); 

} 

function win(r) { 
    //console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode); 
    //console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    alert("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
} 

function fail(error) { 

    switch (error.code) { 
        case FileTransferError.FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR: 
            alert("Photo file not found"); 
            break; 

        case FileTransferError.INVALID_URL_ERR: 
            alert("Bad Photo URL"); 
            break; 

        case FileTransferError.CONNECTION_ERR:
            alert("Connection error"); 
            break; 
    } 

    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code); 

}                   

</script>
</body>
```

Here is my WCF service.

IMyService.cs

```
namespace MyAppService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "SaveImage")]
        string SaveImage();

    }
}
```

MyService.svc.cs

```
namespace MyAppService
{

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class MyService : IMyService
    {

        public string SaveImage()
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["recFile"];
            if (file == null)
                return null;
            string targetFilePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Images\Tree\\" + file.FileName;
            file.SaveAs(targetFilePath);
            return file.FileName.ToString();
        } 
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the error? What does log say?

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at MyAppService.SaveImage()

Comment: I think my service has some issue.        HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["recFile"]; is getting as null

Comment: The best advice I could give you on this, if you have access to a Windows machine, would be to set up [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/), proxy to it from the device, and then inspect the packets going from the device to the server. There can be lots of interesting cross origin issues when dealing with Cordova.

Comment: Have you tested your web service independently? Test it using Google Chrome's extension **Advance REST Client**

Comment: thanks Amol,Jamie for the quick response...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the help.. I found the issue.. When I set  aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" in web.config file of WCF service, I got the  HttpPostedFile.

should try this

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

or

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
```

Thanks..