# Take Picture From Camera And Upload on Server Using WCF Service or HTTP Handler

Tags: c#, wcf, cordova

I want to Store Camera Picture on server so I have user File Upload API of PhoneGap but there is no luck.

**My target platform is Windows Phone 7 and Android. On Windows Phone I am getting "Connection Error" and on Android I am getting File Not found error. I referred this link
[Upload image from phonegap app to WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232183/upload-image-from-phonegap-app-to-wcf-service)
**

Here is my code

```
 $(document).on({
            'pageinit': function (e) {
                $(".divTakePhoto").on('click', function (event) {
                     event.preventDefault();
                     getPicture();
                });
              },
    }, "#pgHome");

function getPicture(source) {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onCaptureSuccess, onCaptureFail,
                        {
                            quality: 10,
                            destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                            sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
                        });
}

function onCaptureFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
};

function onCaptureSuccess(imageURI) {
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    options.fileKey = "recFile";
    var imagefilename = imageURI;
    options.fileName = imagefilename;
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, "http://myserver/MyAppService.svc/SaveImage", win, fail, options);
}


function resolveOnSuccess(entry) {
    fileuri = entry.toURL();
    //console.log(fileuri);
}

function fsFail(message) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(message));
}

function win(r) {
    alert("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
}

function fail(error) {
    switch (error.code) {
        case FileTransferError.FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR:
            alert("Photo file not found");
            break;
        case FileTransferError.INVALID_URL_ERR:
            alert("Bad Photo URL");
            break;
        case FileTransferError.CONNECTION_ERR:
            alert("Connection error");
            break;
    }
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
}
```

> Please help me if I am missing anything.
>       I also tried to post image through $.ajax()
>       here is the code for post image to http handler but it is showing parsing error.

```
function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://myserver/ImageHandler.ashx",
        data: {                
            imgData: imageURI
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            var arr = new Array();
            var responseData = data;
            arr = (data.split("."));
            if (arr[1].toString() != '') {

            }
            else
                alert("Uploaded! " + data);
            $.mobile.changePage("home.html");
            var imageData = responseData.split("-");
        },
        error: function (request, error) {
            alert("Error! " + error);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The first thing I would try is pulling back some basic text first. Do you have anything in the WCF service verified to be working?

Comment: Yes I have more than 10 WCF services which is working properly. Every Server Side operations is performed by WCF services.